# More Fusion Chart Questions

Tags: c#, asp.net, fusioncharts

I almost have this thing working. The last hurdle I have to get over is referencing an XML page. When dealing with Fusion Charts, they reference an XML page to retrieved the chart information like so:

```
    <script type="text/javascript"><!--
FusionCharts.setCurrentRenderer('javascript');
var myChart = new FusionCharts("/Dashboard/Charts/MSCombi2D.swf", "popChartDiv", "100%", "100%", "0");
myChart.setXMLUrl("/Data/Data.xml");
myChart.render("test");

var myChart1 = new FusionCharts("/Dashboard/Charts/MSCombi2D.swf", "Line3ChartDiv", "100%", "100%", "0");
myChart1.setXMLUrl("/Data/Data.xml");
myChart1.render("test");

function chartRender(arg) {
    if (arg == "Tab1") {
        myChart.render("test");
    }
    else if (arg == "Tab2") {
        myChart1.render("test");
    }
    return false;

}
// -->  
</script>
```

This script here within the code is giving me the problem:

```
myChart.setXMLUrl("/Data/Data.xml");
```

My chart information is coming from a C# page not an XML page. So my question is, what do I need to put here in place of setXMLUrl() since it is not coming from an XML page? Here is the C# information:

```
public void SetLine3Chart(DataSet exDT)
    {
        StringBuilder xmlData = new StringBuilder();

        xmlData.Append("<chart caption='Current Period: Total Months: 12' chartBottomMargin='8' chartTopMargin='04' captionPadding='01' xAxisNamePadding='-20' yAxisNamePadding='05' chartRightMargin='20' showBorder='0' yAxisName='' xAxisName='' numberPrefix='$' formatNumberScale='0'>");
        xmlData.Append("<categories>");
        xmlData.Append("<category label='January'/>");
        xmlData.Append("<category label='February'/>");
        xmlData.Append("<category label='March'/>");
        xmlData.Append("<category label='April'/>");
        xmlData.Append("<category label='May'/>");
        xmlData.Append("<category label='June'/>");
        xmlData.Append("</categories>");

        xmlData.Append("<dataset seriesName='Budget Spent' >");
        xmlData.Append("<set value='3478'/>");
        xmlData.Append("<set value='2557'/>");
        xmlData.Append("<set value='5379'/>");
        xmlData.Append("<set value='4987'/>");
        xmlData.Append("<set value='1790'/>");
        xmlData.Append("<set value='6367'/>");
        xmlData.Append("</dataset>");

        xmlData.Append("<dataset seriesName='Average Spending' renderAs='Line'>");
        xmlData.Append("<set value='4375'/>");
        xmlData.Append("<set value='4675'/>");
        xmlData.Append("<set value='6354'/>");
        xmlData.Append("<set value='7648'/>");
        xmlData.Append("<set value='4578'/>");
        xmlData.Append("<set value='4763'/>");
        xmlData.Append("</dataset>");
        xmlData.Append("<styles>");
        xmlData.Append("<definition>");
        xmlData.Append("<style name='Font_0' type='font' font='Arial' size='12' color='666666' rightMargin='15' />");
        xmlData.Append("</definition>");
        xmlData.Append("<application>");
        xmlData.Append("<apply toObject='CAPTION' styles='Font_0'/>");
        xmlData.Append("</application>");
        xmlData.Append("</styles>");
        xmlData.Append("</chart>");

        Literal9.Text = FusionCharts.RenderChart("/Dashboard/Charts/MSCombi2D.swf", "", xmlData.ToString(), "line3Chart", "100%", "100%", false, false);
    }
```

The file name is called Scripts.ascx.cs .

Answer (score 0):

Just provide the file name to the scripts.aspx file in `setXMLUrl`. Just ensure that the file outputs an XML string.